# Avoiding Latex Error when using letter document class

Tags: conditionals

With the following style file I get the `No counter 'section' defined.`
because the `letter` document class does not support `sections`.

```
%% piston.sty
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames*,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\newtheorem{piston_dfin}{Definition}[section]
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

This is the document

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{letter}

\usepackage{piston}

\begin{document}
  Some Text Here
\end{document}
```

I would like to modify the style file in such a way that using the
style file when using the `letter` class won't send tha Latex error.

What can I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  \@ifundefined{\c@section}
     {}
     {\newtheorem{piston_dfin}{Definition}[section]}
```

or of course you could use a similar test from expl3
or etoolbox (why are you loading etoolbox, expl3 covers most of its functionality)

```
\int_if_exist:NT\c@section
 { \newtheorem{piston_dfin}{Definition}[section] }
```

Comment: I am including options in my style file. Using `\newif\ifMathsymbols`, `\DeclareOption{Mathsymbols}{\Mathsymbolstrue}`, `\ProcessOptions`,  `\ifMathsymbols
\RequirePackage{stix} \fi`.

Comment: If I can use `expl3`, I would much prefer to use the `expl3` functionality.

Comment: @Veak I already added the expl3 version

Comment: You asked why I use `etoolbox`.  So I answered.

Comment: @Veak ??? there is no etoolbox related code in that comment

Comment: The first solution is not `expl3` ? Can one include options with `expl3` to save me from calling `etoolbox` ?

Comment: `Mathsymbols` is a weirdly confusing option name to load stix fonts. You get the same symbols with the better stix2 fonts and almost the same set with amssymb. the option name gives no clue about its functionality.

Comment: there is nothing related to etoolbox in any code you have shown, just delete the line. @Veak

Comment: It was just a small example to show you which calls I use when defining options.  Had nothing to do with usefulness.

Comment: Have looked at the `etoolbox` documentation.  I do not seem to be using any of its commands.  Is `\ProcessOptions` part of Latex Core ?

Comment: yes of course, as documented in clsguide